# Selecting rowset when value exists in one of 5 tables with different amounts of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I Need to return the entire row from whatever table contains 'value' in the Filename column (A column each of the tables contain), but the tables do not have the same number of columns, and each table has unique columns with their own specific data types (The only column Name/Type they have in common is the Filename column that I need to check for 'value').

Ideally, I would be able to do something along the lines of:
    SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5
    WHERE Filename = 'someValue'
Since all tables share the same column name for the Filename.

I have tried using Union but have issues since the number of columns and datatypes of the tables do not align.
I have also tried every combination of JOIN I could find.

I'm sure this could be accomplished with IF EXISTS, but that would be many, many lines of what seems like unnecessary code. Hoping there is a more elegant solution. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And how do your tables look like? What have you tried so far? Please read [ask] and how to prepare [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I edited it in hopes that it cleared up any issues. 
I did read over the "How to Ask" that you posted. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Also: which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server through MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @MJF Does the result have to be in one resultset?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't need to be. As long as I am able to still obtain the data from the other columns in the table that contained the value somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to join the tables together. First create temporary table where you store the input. And then join the tables with this temporary to get all records you want. When there is no record for that filename in the table, then you will get NULL values.

```
create table Table1 (id int,value int);
insert into Table1 values (1,10)

create table Table2 (id int,value int);
insert into Table2 values (1,20)

create table Table3 (id int,value int);
insert into Table3 values (2,30)
```

Here is the query itself

```
create table #tmp (id int)
insert into #tmp
values (1)

select t.id, t1.value, t2.value, t3.value from #tmp as t

left join Table1 as t1
on t.id = t1.id
left join Table2 as t2
on t.id = t2.id
left join Table3 as t3
on t.id = t3.id
```

And this is what you get

```
id  value   value   value
 1     10      20    NULL
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, Thanks!

I was able to get a working version using the IF EXISTS option as well. Do you happen to know which of the options between my solution and yours would be the faster and more efficient one to end up using?
Its going to run over hundreds of thousands of times when it is in production

Comment: I don't know. Best way is to try it and then check results. Since you are on MS SQL server, there are two very useful commands along with execution plans - `set statistics time on` and `set statistics io on`

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out. I appreciate your time helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

this should work too:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1='SELECT * FROM ? where filename = ''someValue''',
@whereand='AND o.id in (select object_id from sys.tables where name in (''Table1'',''Table2'',''Table3''))'
```